# Error message displayed on wrong from when multiple on page

Tags: php, validation, silverstripe

I have multiple basic forms on a page, called by a getter with a unique ID relevant to the content being displayed:

```
public function getForm($ID) {
    $form = Form::create(
        $this,
        '',
        $fields = FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Name', 'Name'),
            HiddenField::create('ID', 'ID', $ID)
        ),
        FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('Submit', 'Submit')
        )
    );
}
```

If the `Name` isn't unique I want to set an error message in the `submit` function:

```
public function Submit($data, $form = null) {
    //check stuff
    $form->addErrorMessage('Name', 'Name is already taken', 'error');
    return $this->redirectBack();
}
```

This works but the error message is displayed on the first form rather than the relevant form.

How can I put the error message on the right form? I'm using SilverStripe 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

When using `addErrorMessage` this will add the message to the relevantly named `FormField`.  You would be better off changing all the fields to be unique in some way and then adding the message to ta unique field.  Using the ID of the record could work:

```
public function getForm($ID) {
    $form = Form::create(
        $this,
        '',
        FieldList::create(
            TextField::create('Name_'.$ID, 'Name'),
            HiddenField::create('ID', 'ID', $ID)
        ),
        FieldList::create(
            FormAction::create('Submit', 'Submit')
        )
    );
}

public function Submit($data, $form = null) {
    //check stuff
    $form->addErrorMessage('Name_'.$data['ID'], 'Name is already taken', 'error');
    return $this->redirectBack();
}
```